# Can I create an abstraction to hide my "checking the cache" logic?

Tags: java, oop, caching, design-patterns, interface

I have `getResponse()` methods which build a response from data fetched from the database (or pre-saved in a `SavedData` object). I would like to find a way to abstract out the "check savedData" logic from my `getResponse()` methods. Ideally, I want to figure out a way where my `getResponse()` methods don't even know `SavedData` exists, it is just hidden behind some interface. Is there a good abstraction here I can use to clean up this code?

The following is just pseudo-code. For each field which is returned in the `getResponse()` JSON object, they first check if that field has been saved in some `SavedData` and use it if it has, otherwise, they need to query the DB for the field.

```java
interface ResponseGetter {
  public Response getResponse(String userID, SavedData savedData);
}

class A implements ResponseGetter {
  public Response getResponse(String userID, SavedData savedData) {           
      List<String> foo;
      int bar;
      String bizz;

      foo = savedData.get(userID, "foo");
      if (foo == null) {
        foo = loadFooFromDB(userID);
      }
      bar = savedData.get(userID, "bar");
      if (bar == null) {
        bar = loadBarFromDB(userID);
      }
      bizz = savedData.get(userID, "bizz");
      if (bizz == null) {
        bizz = loadBizzFromDB(userID);
      }

      JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
      json.put("foo", foo);
      json.put("bar", bar);
      json.put("bizz", biz);
      return new Response(json);
  }

  private List<String> loadFooFromDB(String userID) {
     List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
     DB db = this.getDB();
     String query = "SELECT foo FROM SomeTable WHERE user_id=" + userID;
     Results results = db.executeQuery(query);
     for (Result result : results) {
         returnList.add(result.toString());
     }

     return returnList;
  }
}

class B implements ResponseGetter {
  public Response getResponse(String userID, SavedData savedData) {           
      List<String> baz;
      int qux;
      String corge;

      baz = savedData.get(userID, "baz");
      if (baz == null) {
        baz = loadBazFromDB(userID);
      }
      qux = savedData.get(userID, "qux");
      if (qux == null) {
        qux = loadQuxFromDB(userID);
      }
      corge = savedData.get(userID, "corge");
      if (corge == null) {
        corge = loadCorgeFromDB(userID);
      }
      
    
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
      json.put("baz", baz);
      json.put("qux", qux);
      json.put("corge", corge);
        
      return new Response(json);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have something in mind, but first I wanted to ask you, each implementation class, A, B etc, have it's own load methods like, loadCorgeFromDB right ? Do you have the pseudo-code for these loaders methods ? It would help if you do.

Comment: Yep that's correct. I added pseudo-code for an example loadFooFromDB() method

Answer (score 0):

I would use generics and the [Strategy Design Pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-strategy-pattern).

I didn't really know what types and classes you could give up, since you provided a pseudo-code.

If I forgot to put something importante, please comment.

---

But I would go with something like this:

```
interface ResponseGetter<R> {
R getResponse(String userId, String dataToCheck, SavedData<R> savedData, Function<String, R> lambda);
}

class DB<R> {
public R executeQuery(String query) {
    return null;
}
}

interface SavedData<R> {
    public R get(String userId, String name);
}

class SomeClass<R> implements ResponseGetter<R> {

    @Override
    public R getResponse(String userId, String dataToCheck, SavedData<R> savedData, Function<String, R> lambda) {
        R checkedData = savedData.get(userId, dataToCheck);
        return checkedData == null ? loadDataFromDB(userId, lambda) : checkedData;
    }

    public R loadDataFromDB(String userId, Function<String, R> lambda) {
        return lambda.apply(userId);
    }
}

class SavedDataImpl<R> implements SavedData<R> {

    @Override
    public R get(String userId, String name) {
        return null;
    }
}

class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // foo
        SomeClass<List<String>> someClass = new SomeClass<>();
        SavedDataImpl<List<String> savedDataImpl = new SavedDataImpl<>();
        DB<List<String>> db = new DB<>();

        List<String> foo = someClass.getResponse("1", "foo", savedDataImpl, (String userId) -> {
        List<String> result = db.executeQuery("SELECT foo FROM SomeTable WHERE user_id=" + userId);
        return result;
    });

    // bar
    SomeClass<Integer> someClassTwo = new SomeClass<>();
    SavedDataImpl<Integer savedDataImplTwo = new SavedDataImpl<>();
    DB<Integer> dbTwo = new DB<>();

    Integer bar = someClassTwo.getResponse("1", "bar", savedDataImplTwo, (String userId) -> {
        Integer result = dbTwo.executeQuery("SELECT bar FROM SomeTable WHERE user_id=" + userId);
        return result;
    });

    // bizz
    SomeClass<String> someClassThree = new SomeClass<>();
    SavedDataImpl<String savedDataImplThree = new SavedDataImpl<>();
    DB<String> dbThree = new DB<>();

    String bizz = someClassThree.getResponse("1", "bizz", savedDataImplThree, (String userId) -> {
        String result = dbThree.executeQuery("SELECT bizz FROM SomeTable WHERE user_id=" + userId);
        return result;
    });

    Map json = new HashMap();
    json.put("foo", foo);
    json.put("bar", bar);
    json.put("bizz", bizz);

}
}
```

That way you are abstracting the behavior of the how to get the data and wich data to get.

I just formatted the response in a Map for simplicity.